# Pure CSS Animating Mobile menu activated using radiobutton

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I have a Mobile menu that should be forming X when clicked, however it would not respond and is stuck on its shape. I don't know why it acted that why, but as far as I have analyzed, this code should animate the Menu to form X when clicked. I am attaching the code for reference.

These are the CSS and HTML

```css
/* Checkbox Hack */
input[type=checkbox] {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  left: -5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}

/* Default State */
.divko {
  background: green;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Toggled State */
.myspan {
  display: block;
  width: 33px;
  height: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;
  background: #cdcdcd;
  border-radius: 3px;
  z-index: 1;
  transform-origin: 4px 0px;
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0), background 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0), opacity 0.55s ease;
}

.myspan:first-child {
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}

.myspan:nth-last-child(2) {
  transform-origin: 0% 100%;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .myspan {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-2px, -1px);
  background: #232323;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .divko {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div for="toggle-1"> <span class="myspan"></span>
  <span class="myspan"></span>
  <span class="myspan"></span></div>
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle-1">
<div class="divko">I'm controlled by toggle. No JavaScript!</div>
```

Here is the dabblet
http://dabblet.com/gist/5b4667ecc7255c228cd488c080140d95

Comment: Hey I got it to work with your current CSS by modifying your html place the input before the first span. The CSS wasn't being applied to it because you weren't actually selecting it because of its position.

Comment: Indeed, I was able to fix it by applying Ori's fix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the checkbox before the div I've give the `.menu` class to, and apply the rule on `input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .menu > .myspan`.

```css
/* Checkbox Hack */
input[type=checkbox] {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  left: -5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}

/* Default State */
.divko {
  background: green;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Toggled State */
.myspan {
  display: block;
  width: 33px;
  height: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;
  background: #cdcdcd;
  border-radius: 3px;
  z-index: 1;
  transform-origin: 4px 2px;
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0), background 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0), opacity 0.55s ease;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .menu > .myspan {
  opacity: 1;
  background: #232323;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .menu > .myspan:first-child {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .menu > .myspan:nth-child(2) {
  transform: translate(-100px);
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .menu > .myspan:last-child {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .divko {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle-1">

<div for="toggle-1" class="menu">
  <span class="myspan"></span>
  <span class="myspan"></span>
  <span class="myspan"></span>
</div>

<div class="divko">I'm controlled by toggle. No JavaScript!</div>
```